# Clickable Button without JavaScript Output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to have a button that is clickable, but `onClick` it will activate a JavaScript function, but I don't want it to be the `<button>` element as it will replace it with a ugly looking rectangle, which I just want the div element to be clickable and it will make it give a response. If it's a quiz, and there's a question to define a word, I want it to be able to click one of the generated answers and based on what is clicked, it will either show a check mark for correct or a X for incorrect.

## PROBLEM

I need to have clickable `<td>` elements for a 3x3 table that will, `onClick`, output a JavaScript command/function, without having to use `<button>` for each `<td>` element.

## EXAMPLE

Generated word 'FRUIT' is in place. The 9 possible answers are 'Green Beans', 'Corn', 'Apple', 'Potatoes', 'Cucumber', 'Tomato', 'Carrot', 'Broccoli', and 'Cabbage'. All of the `<td>` elements are clickable with [what I had in mind working] `<td><a href="determineAnswer()">Carrot</a></td>`, and if 'Apple' is clicked, it will output that function and check if it's correct. If it is, it will change the `display: hidden` for the checkmark to visible until the button is clicked. Otherwise, it will do the same for the X.

## CODE

### JS: Change answer based on word function

```
function grabWord()  {
  var word = document.getElementById("outputNumber");
  var answer1 = document.getElementById("output1");
  var answer2 = document.getElementById("output2");
  var answer3 = document.getElementById("output3");
  var answer4 = document.getElementById("output4");
  var answer5 = document.getElementById("output5");
  var answer6 = document.getElementById("output6");
  var answer7 = document.getElementById("output7");
  var answer8 = document.getElementById("output8");
  var answer9 = document.getElementById("output9");
  if(word.innerHTML == "Word 1")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W1";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W9";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 2")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W2";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W2";    
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 3")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W3";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W3";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 4")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W4";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W4";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 5")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W5";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W5";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 6")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W6";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W6";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 7")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W7";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W7";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 8")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W8";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W8";
  }
  else if(word.innerHTML == "Word 9")  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer2.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer3.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer4.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer5.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer6.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer7.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer8.innerHTML = "A4W9";
    answer9.innerHTML = "A4W9";
  }
  else  {
    answer1.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer2.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer3.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer4.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer5.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer6.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer7.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer8.innerHTML = "Error";
    answer9.innerHTML = "Error";
  }
}
```

### JS: Creating the Word itself

```
function changeRandom()  {
  var x = document.getElementById('outputNumber').innerHTML
  if(x == 1)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 1";
  } else if(x == 2)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 2";
  } else if(x == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 3";
  } else if(x == 4)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 4" 
  } else if(x == 5) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 5"
  }
  else if(x == 6) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 6"
  } 
  else if(x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 7"
  }
  else if(x == 8) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 8"
  }
  else if(x == 9) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 9"
  }
  else if(x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 10"
  }
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Error :c"
  }
}
```

### HTML: The selective elements

```
  <table>
    <p id="outputNumber" class="outputNumber">Your word will go here; Click the Randomize Button!</p>
    <tr>
      <td id="output1"></td>
      <td id="output2"></td>
      <td id="output3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="output4"></td>
      <td id="output5"></td>
      <td id="output6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="output7"></td>
      <td id="output8"></td>
      <td id="output9"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

### WORKABLE CODEPEN

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/TheGamingHideout/pen/JoPVZw)

Comment: FYI your code could be *massivley* condensed if you used some loops.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I'm not 100% familiar with the loop functions.

Comment: @DavidVex - what you are trying to do is very, very basic.  Loops are also very, very basic.  I recommend some reading.  First - event handlers:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers -and- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener  -then- Loops:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for my answer, I've done some major code-cleanup for you along with providing the additional event handlers necessary to make the table cells clickable (at the end of the JavaScript snippet).  I hope that you use this code as a learning tool to improve your own JavaScript ability, and not just take it to use in this one project.

```js
// This is an unchanged function that was in the original CodePen provided, that I'm assuming was "borrowed" from elsewhere since you're not familiar with loops.
        function getRandom() {
            var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
            var gen_nums = [];
            function in_array(array, el) {
                for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
                    if (array[i] == el) return true;
                return false;
            }
            function get_rand(array) {
                var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
                if (!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
                    gen_nums.push(rand);
                    return rand;
                }
                return get_rand(array);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                return (get_rand(nums));
            }
        }

// EDIT:  This acts like a "Dictionary" for your words.  Each array must contain exactly 9 words
    var words = [
        { word: "Fruits A-B", array: ["Apple", "Apricot", "Avacado", "Banana", "Breadfruit", "Bilberry", "Blackberry", "Blackcurrant", "Blueberry"] },
        { word: "Fruits B-C", array: ["Boysenberry", "Cantaloupe", "Currant", "Cherry", "Cherimoya", "Cloudberry", "Coconut", "Cranberry", "Cucumber"] },
        { word: "Fruits D-G", array: ["Damson", "Date", "Dragonfruit", "Durian", "Eggplant", "Elderberry", "Feijoa", "Fig", "Goji berry"] },
        { word: "Fruits G-K", array: ["Gooseberry", "Grape", "Grapefruit", "Guava", "Huckleberry", "Honeydew", "Jackfruit", "Jambul", "Kiwi fruit"] },
        { word: "Fruits K-M", array: ["Kumquat", "Lemon", "Lime", "Loquat", "Lychee", "Mango", "Marion berry", "Melon", "Miracle fruit"] },
        { word: "Fruits M-P", array: ["Mulberry", "Nectarine", "Nut", "Olive", "Orange", "Papaya", "Passionfruit", "Peach", "Pepper"] },
        { word: "Fruits P-Q", array: ["Pear", "Persimmon", "Physalis", "Plum", "Pineapple", "Pomegranate", "Pomelo", "Purple Mangosteen", "Quince"] },
        { word: "Fruits R-T", array: ["Raspberry", "Rambutan", "Salal berry", "Salmon berry", "Satsuma", "Star fruit", "Strawberry", "Tomarillo", "Tomato"] },
        { word: "Fruits U-Z", array: ["Ugli fruit", "Watermelon", "Bell pepper", "Chili pepper", "Clementine", "Mandarine", "Tangerine", "Blood Orange", "Rock Melon"] }
    ];

// EDIT: This is the new condensed grabWord() function
    function grabWord() {
        var word = document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML;
        var wordIndex;
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (words[i].word === word) {
                wordIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            document.getElementById("output" + i).innerHTML = words[wordIndex].array[i-1];
        }
    }

// EDIT: This is the fixed changeRandom() function
    function changeRandom() {
        document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = words[(getRandom() - 1)].word;
        grabWord();
    }

// Modified event handler that was in the original CodePen
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            changeRandom();
        })
        
// New event handler for the clicking of the cells in the table.
        var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert(this.innerHTML);
            });
        }
```

```css
table, tbody, tr, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="header" class="animated infinite pulse">
        <h2>School Learning Kit!</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="header2">
        <h5>This kit has multiple tools for learning <i>AND</i>school, including calculators, word definitions (quiz, study guide, etc) and more! Consult the JavaScript comments etc) and more! Consult the JavaScript comments (third box) for information on how to (third box) for information on how to change each tool to fit your needs!</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="randomizer">
        <div id="wordOutput">
            <div id="button">
                <button id="myBtn">Randomize!</button><br />
                <p>
                    Click this button to generate a random word!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="answers" class="answers">
            <p id="outputNumber" class="outputNumber">Your word will go here; Click the Randomize Button!</p>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="output1" tabindex="1"></td>
                        <td id="output2" tabindex="1"></td>
                        <td id="output3" tabindex="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="output4" tabindex="1"></td>
                        <td id="output5" tabindex="1"></td>
                        <td id="output6" tabindex="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="output7" tabindex="1"></td>
                        <td id="output8" tabindex="1"></td>
                        <td id="output9" tabindex="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This answers EVERYTHING EXCEPT ONE THING: I would need to choose the answers for each TD element based on the word; Can you update that to make it select-able for each word?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Could you provide some more detail?

Comment: Okay, so for the updated grabWord() function, it just makes it the A4W and then the number, right? I posted the code with that because it wasn't complete, and it would have to be setup so people that use the completed kit could change the grabWord() function and manually change the possible answers for each word. For example, if the word is 'Word 1', I would have to have the code setup so that I can make it not just 1 same word with a number after it, but manually be able to setup each word manually like it was before. Please, and thank you for condensing and organizing it! @HowardRenollet

Comment: As soon as you can update that, I will accept your answer as a suitable answer... the checkmark thing.. um... yea!

Comment: @DavidVex - I've modified the `grabWord()` function and added in a "Dictionary" that allows you to associate 9 different words with one main word.  This makes it very easy to modify.  I marked all of my changes with `// EDIT:`  Again - I highly recommend using this as a learning tool to expand your JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Please check my profile and add me on skype/steam. You're a great helper, and I can never find help like yours on here. Please? Thanks btw! <3

Comment: Hey, another thing; I need a similar function for the words. How can I do that? Because the words aren't supposed to be just "Word 1"

Comment: @DavidVex - Ok, so for this edit, I changed the `grabWord()` function, the `changeRandom()` function, and the `words` variable.  `words` is now an array of objects.  All you have to do is make the changes you want in `words`.

Comment: The great thing about this, is the `words` object is now valid JSON, so you could use AJAX to pull your JSON from the server instead of hard-coding it in the JavaScript.  That's probably a little advanced for where you're at right now, but the fact that the word list could be dynamically produced, now makes this the ideal solution to your problem.

Comment: One last question; Would I change the `Fruits X-Y` to like `Fruits A-B`, `Vegetables C-D`, etc?"

Comment: Yes, the `Fruits A-B` is where `Word 1` used to be, then all of the other words that correlate to that main word for the table are in the array within that same object

Comment: Thanks so much. Please add me on one of the social media listed on my profile; I never received such good help in such a patient, nice manner

Comment: The click function isn't doing what I need to do; Please look at my  latest question

Answer (score 1):

Add a tabindex to the html of the div you want clickable , then add onclick.

```html
<table><tr>
<td id="clickable" tabindex="1" onclick="alert('clicked')">Click me</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: I'll try this now, honestly I think it will work but it won't let me accept it as an answer for another 8 minutes.

Comment: It worked c: Thanks! I'll accept it as an answer when it lets me :p

Comment: **Note:** It's not really a good idea to place JavaScript code and events inside HTML, it's better to separate them and place them inside JavaScript.